# How to update a specific div from an ajax response object returns a form in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

An ajax request is sent to Spring MVC controller when a particular drop down is selected. Form page created in JSP. Controller response object returns the full form to JSP. So, when I use the updateHTML, it returns another form under the form loaded previously.

I need to update only a particular div which contains another drop down list. I think I have got two solutions. Sending data only for that select box from controller. Or else I can try to update only the div which I want to change from the response.

Two drop downs in the JSP page

```
   <b>Country:</b>
  <spring:bind path="company.country">
    <font color="red">
      <b><c:out value="${status.errorMessage}"/></b>
    </font>
    <br/>
    <select id="countryNameField" name="countryNameField" onchange="getStates();">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <c:forEach var="country" items="${countryList}">
            <option value='<c:out value="${country}"/>'
                <c:if test="${status.value == country}">selected</c:if>>
                   <c:out value="${country}"/>
            </option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
  </spring:bind>
  <p/>

<div id="statesManager" name="statesManager" style="display:none">
   <b>Manager:</b>
     <spring:bind path="company.manager">
       <font color="red">
         <b><c:out value="${status.errorMessage}"/></b>
       </font>
    <br/>
    <select name="manager">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <c:forEach var="manager" items="${managerList}">
            <option value='<c:out value="${manager}"/>'
                <c:if test="${status.value == manager}">selected</c:if>> 
                  <c:out value="${manager}"/>
            </option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
  </spring:bind>
  <p/>
</div>
```

Response object returned from controller contains the full form. I want to update only the div

```
<div id="statesManager" name="statesManager" style="display:none">
```

Java script code handles the Ajax part

```
var response = httpRequest.responseText;
                alert(response);
                document.getElementById("statesManager").innerHTML = response;
                document.getElementById("statesManager").style.display="block";
```

Comment: are you using jQuery ? (you tagged it)

Comment: I don't use jquery. I don't mind trying using jquery if there is any way to get it done. Appreciate your concern. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want me to remove the jquery tag ? if you want to use jquery look at the `load()` method, does everything you need ! -> http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: `$('#statesManager').load('your URL');` simple hey ?

Comment: I tagged it because to find if there is a way to do it in jquery. Actually I have not worked with jquery before. But, I heard that this can be done by jquery. That's why I tagged it. Thanks for the support.

Comment: To clear out a misconception: jQuery is just a JS library which is written in 100% pure JS. It only simplifies Ajax request handling and HTML DOM traversion and manipulation by useful functions and chaining, and last but not least it also abstracts all cross-browser matters away. Anything which can be done with jQuery can also be done with "plain vanilla" JS; it only requires more lines of own code and more testing.

Comment: I tried with the above code. But it gives an error. I haven't worked with jquery before. I can understand that this error comes because I have to add a library to this project. Error says that $ is not defined. I'm trying to figure it out. Thanks a lot for your support and appreciate your quick response.

Comment: Appreciate if I can get a link for a tutorial. I didn't find a good tutorial which goes from start. Thank you

Comment: I added this code. It's not working yet. Same like before form is getting loaded again. Any idea about this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out the answer. Thanks a lot for your support on jQuery. 
This is the line worked for me.

```
    $('#statesManager').load('yoururl #manager', 
{ 'parameterName': $('#countryNameField option:selected').val() });
```